How to Change contents of Extent Spark reports with Cucumber Java
I am using Playwright with Cucumber BDD for automation and extentreports-cucumber7-adapter by grasshopper to generate test reports. I am looking for a work around where I can edit contents of the extent report generated like changing a particular text in report, any Label etc, username, password etc. Attaching screenshot for reference. For ex how can I change Test@123 to something different like *****.

My feature file:
Feature: Testing Login Flow

  Scenario Outline: Login to the Portal with the correct credentials
    Given User launched Login Page
    When User verifies the Page title
    When User enters valid credentials on page using the id "<id>" and password "<Password>"
    Then User clicks on the Log On button

    Examples: 
      | id    | Password   |  
      | Test | Test@123 |  | 

extent.properties:
extent.reporter.spark.start=true
extent.reporter.spark.out=target/Cucumber-Reports/extent-Report.html
extent.reporter.spark.config=src/test/resources/spark-config.xml
extent.reporter.spark.base64imagesrc=true
screenshot.dir=TestScreenshots/
screenshot.rel.path=../.././TestScreenshots/

spark-config.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<extentreports>
    <configuration>
        <!-- report theme -->
        <!-- standard, dark -->
        <theme>dark</theme>

        <!-- document encoding -->
        <!-- defaults to UTF-8 -->
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>

        <!-- protocol for script and stylesheets -->
        <!-- defaults to https -->
        <protocol>https</protocol>

        <!-- title of the document -->
        <documentTitle>Testing Report</documentTitle>

        <!-- report name - displayed at top-nav -->
        <reportName> Testing Report</reportName>

        <!-- view report without internet -->
        <offlineMode>false</offlineMode>

        <thumbnailForBase64>true</thumbnailForBase64>

        <!-- custom javascript -->
        <js></js>

        <!-- custom styles -->
        <css></css>
    </configuration>
</extentreports>

Upon researching I found 2 workarounds. First I can keep my credentials as environment variables and remove Examples and Scenario Outline from feature file. Second we have to use javascript in js tag of spark-config.xml. But I want to know is there any way we can do it from Java code.
